# AJAX call to web service reports "undefined"

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax

I'm developing a web application using .net/c#/jQuery.

I want to develop an AJAX function in a user register page to detect if the user name has been chosen by others already.

Since the register form is in a user control, and a scriptmanager control is in the master page, I added a ScriptManagerProxy control in that user control. The js function was wrapped into a file called a.js.

The webservice is called Vet.asmx.  When called it always reports that "Vet" is undefined, but I don't know why. The code of ScriptManagerProxy is:

```
<asp:ScriptManagerProxy ID="ScriptManagerProxy1" runat="server">
    <Scripts>
        <asp:ScriptReference Path="~/Menu/a.js" />
    </Scripts>
    <Services>
        <asp:ServiceReference Path="~/WebService/Vet.asmx" />
    </Services>
</asp:ScriptManagerProxy>
```

The Vet.cs is

```
public Vet()
{

    //Uncomment the following line if using designed components 
    //InitializeComponent(); 
}

[WebMethod]
public string SearchUserName(string name)
{
    ...
}
```

My a.js code

```
jQuery("[id$='tb_UserName']").blur(function() {
    var login = jQuery("[id$='tb_UserName']").val();
    Vet.SearchUserName(login, SearchUserNameCallback);
});
function SearchUserNameCallback(result) {
    if (result == "Y") {
        jQuery('#userInfo').html("This user name has already been taken");
    } else {
        jQuery('#userInfo').html("Congratulations!You have a new user name.");
    }
}
```

I'm sure the web method and the js function have no issues other than it cannot find the "Vet" web service. Any idea?

Comment: can you reach the WS via your browser (no JS - just url)?

Comment: It's not a c# function, it's a asmx file, the code is separated.

Comment: Yes, I can reach the web service via url

Comment: @Jeff B -  This is in fact possible to call an asmx web service from client code. The ScriptManager should generate a javascript proxy. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163499.aspx

Comment: Ah, that's the part I didn't understand about the ScriptManager.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is your `Vet` class decorated with the [[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.services.scriptserviceattribute.aspx) attribute?

Comment: In the past, I've had to include the namespace when calling the proxy in Javascript in addition to what RoccoC5 said. ie: `MyNamespace.Vet.SearchUser(login,callback)`

Answer (score 0):

I would use an ajax enabled wcf service. that makes connections via jQuery ajax absolutely easy.
Or if a full webservice is not needed you could integrate a webmethod into your page and call the webmethod directly from clientside.